# Google Play Error Retrieving Information RPC:S-2:AEC-2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Whenever I try to update an app, I get the error in the question title. I am also unable to view my installed apps. I've already tried wiping the store's data and cache, and removing and readding my account. Nothing helps.

I'm using a Droid Turbo running 4.4.4. Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same problem. I have a nexus 9, running Lollipop. It only happens with the Google+ app. Research I've done says it might be a problem on Google's side. There were a couple of people who signed in using another Google account and downloaded apps that way. Haven't tried it yet.

Update: tried using another account and it didn't work.

Update: it's Google's problem. Read comments in Google Play.

Comment: Could you please share some link. My app is also struggling by this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded a new APK to the store today and I'm having the same problem with my application (BeepMe), I tried to install it on various devices and got the same error.
My guess - it's a problem on Google side, maybe on a recently uploaded APKs.

Answer (score 1):

For fixing this issue just do as following:
Settings -> Application Manager -> Google Play Store -> Clear data.

And then try again...