# RPC:S-2:AEC-2 when trying to install Facebook

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, updates, google-play-services

The phone is a Moto G running Android 4.4.4.
The problem happens when trying to install Facebook.

I've tried clearing the cache for Google Play Services and Google Play Store.
The "Uninstall updates" button in Google Play Services is greyed out.

How can I fix this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: Very related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87489/google-play-error-retrieving-information-rpcs-2aec-2

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I found that post and tried everything before I submitted this question.

Comment: It fixed itself after a few hours when installing it from play.google.com. I suppose Google's servers were in a broken/inconsistent state?

Comment: It seems just like the answer on the other question... which is actually Google-side issue.